How to conclude the non-existence of limit
Let $f(x, y) = \dfrac{x^n + y^n}{x^2 - y^2}$, $n > 2$, be defined in $U = \left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \neq x, y \neq -x\right\}$. My problem is to determine the existence of $\lim\limits_{\substack{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0) \\ (x, y) \in U}} f(x, y)$.
The solution offered by a professor is the following:
Let $V = \left\{(x, x + x^p) : x > 0\right\}$, $p > n - 1$. If $(x, y) \in V$ then
$$f(x, y) = f\left(x, x + x^p\right) = \dfrac{x^n + \left(x + x^p\right)^n}{x^2 - \left(x + x^p\right)^2} = -\dfrac{x^n + x^n + nx^{n - 1 + p} + \cdots + x^{np}}{2x^{p + 1} + x^{2p}}.$$
As $p > n - 1$, if $x \rightarrow 0$ then $f\left(x, x + x^p\right) \rightarrow \infty$. Thus, $f$ is not convergent when $(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)$ in $U$.
My question is how could I come up with this idea. Firstly, I'd have to think about the non-existence instead of the existence, and still I wouldn't know how to get to the set $V$ in order to prove it. Moreover, is there another way to do it?

How to think of it? The function $f$ is clearly undefined (so potentially unbounded) on the paths $|x|=|y|$. That means you want a path that asymptotically approaches one of those, so $y$ is almost equal to $x$, but with a little bit left over for separation. Or $y=x+h(x)$ where $h(0)=0$

As for the "firstly": we always have to consider both existence and non-existence when we don't know the answer. Ideally we would split our brain in two and have the halves work towards the two goals simultaneously :) In practice, we just have to build the habit of being flexible, looking for ways to prove a limit does exist, then switching to looking for ways to prove it doesn't exist (following our intuitions of course, but always being willing to try the other side).

I think you can convert it to polar coordinates $f(x,y)=g(r,\theta)$. Then prove $\partial g(r=0,\theta)/\partial \theta \ne 0 $. This proves the limit changes depending on what path you take to get to the origin.

Here is another way to do it: Let $x = r \cosh \left( t \right)$ and $y = r \sinh \left( t \right)$ where $r \neq 0$. As a consequence,
$$
\frac {{x}^{n} - {y}^{n}}{{x}^{2} - {y}^{2}} = {r}^{n - 2} \left( {\cosh}^{n} \left( t \right) - {\sinh}^{n} \left( t \right) \right),
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
{\cosh}^{n} \left( t \right)
& = {\bigg( \frac {{e}^{t} + {e}^{- t}}{2} \bigg)}^{n} \\
& = {\bigg( \frac {{e}^{t}}{2} \bigg)}^{n} {\big( 1 + {e}^{- 2 t} \big)}^{n} \\
& = {\bigg( \frac {{e}^{t}}{2} \bigg)}^{n} \bigg[ 1 + \binom {n}{1} {e}^{- 2 t} + \binom {n}{2} {e}^{- 4 t} + \binom {n}{3} {e}^{- 6 t} + \cdots \bigg], \\
\\
{\sinh}^{n} \left( t \right)
& = {\bigg( \frac {{e}^{t} - {e}^{- t}}{2} \bigg)}^{n} \\
& = {\bigg( \frac {{e}^{t}}{2} \bigg)}^{n} {\big( 1 - {e}^{- 2 t} \big)}^{n} \\
& = {\bigg( \frac {{e}^{t}}{2} \bigg)}^{n} \bigg[ 1 - \binom {n}{1} {e}^{- 2 t} + \binom {n}{2} {e}^{- 4 t} - \binom {n}{3} {e}^{- 6 t} - \cdots \bigg].
\end{align}
$$
Hence, we derive
$$
{\cosh}^{n} \left( t \right) - {\sinh}^{n} \left( t \right) \ge {\bigg( \frac {{e}^{t}}{2} \bigg)}^{n} \cdot 2 n {e}^{- 2 t} = \frac {n}{2} \, {\bigg( \frac {{e}^{t}}{2} \bigg)}^{n - 2}.
$$
Plugging this back, we have
$$
\frac {{x}^{n} - {y}^{n}}{{x}^{2} - {y}^{2}} \ge \frac {n}{2} \, {\bigg( \frac {r {e}^{t}}{2} \bigg)}^{n - 2}.
$$
As $t \to \infty$, $r {e}^{t} \to \infty$. By comparison, the original limit is non-existent. $\blacksquare$

EDIT:
I misread the numerator: It is ${x}^{n} + {y}^{n}$. In that case, see
$$
{\cosh}^{n} \left( t \right) + {\sinh}^{n} \left( t \right) \ge 2 \cdot {\bigg( \frac {{e}^{t}}{2} \bigg)}^{n}.
$$
Plug this back. We see the conclusion is unaffected: The limit does not exist. $\blacksquare$

It's $x^n + y^n$ instead of $x^n - y^n$. Is it still valid?

@CyclotomicManolo, oops! I've edited my post. And yes, this method applies to ${x}^{n} + {y}^{n}$ as well.

To set the record straight, suppose you have a function $f$ of two variables which is well-defined and continuous at all points $(x,y)$ of an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ except for some point $(x_{0},y_{0})$. That is, the function $f$ is not defined at the point $(x_{0},y_{0})$.
The strategy is as follows. Choose an interval $I_{1}= (a_{1},b_{1})$ with $t_{1}\in (a_1,b_1)$ and invent functions $I_{1}\ni t\mapsto \alpha_{1}(t)$ and $I_{1}\ni t\mapsto \beta_{1}(t)$ such that

$(\alpha_{1}(t),\beta_{1}(t)) \in U$ for all $t\in I_{1}$,
$\lim_{t\to t_1}\alpha_{1}(t)=x_{0}$ and $\lim_{t\to t_1}\beta_{1}(t)=y_{0}$,
The function $ I_{1}\ni t \mapsto g_{1}(t)\in \mathbb{R}$, defined by $g_{1}(t)=f(\alpha_{1}(t),\beta_{1}(t))$ should be simple enough that you can calculate the limit $\lim_{t\to t_1}g_{1}(t)=\lim_{t\to t_1}f(\alpha_{1}(t),\beta_{1}(t))$ easily.

Now, set
$$
V_{1}=\Big\{\big(\alpha_{1}(t),\beta_{1}(t)\big)\in U \;\Big| \; t\in I_{1}  \Big\}
$$
Step 1. If the limit $\lim_{t\to t_1}g_{1}(t)$ does not exist, then the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_{0},y_{0})} f(x,y)$ does not exist. On the other hand, if the limit $\lim_{t\to t_1}g_{1}(t)=L_{1}$ exists, we cannot say that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_{0},y_{0})} f(x,y)$  exists.Go to step 2.
Step 2. Construct functions $\alpha_{2}$, $\beta_{2}$ and $g_{2}$ analogous to functions $\alpha_{1}$, $\beta_{1}$ and $g_{1}$ and a set $V_{2}$ analogous to $V_{1}$. If the limit $\lim_{t\to t_1}g_{2}(t)$ does not exist, then the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_{0},y_{0})} f(x,y)$ does not exist. If the limit $\lim_{t\to t_1}g_{2}(t)=L_{2}$ exists and $L_{1}\neq L_{2}$,then the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_{0},y_{0})} f(x,y)$ does not exist. If $L_{1}=L_{2}$ we cannot say that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_{0},y_{0})} f(x,y)$ exists. Go to step 3.
Step 3. Repeat the step 2, say $n$ times, trying to find a limit $L_{n}=\lim_{t\to t_{n}}g_{n}(t)$ such that $L_{n}\neq L_{n-1}=L_{n-2}=\ldots L_{1}$ or a limit $\lim_{t\to t_{n}}g_{n}(t)$ that does not exist.If you are unsuccessful in finding a limit that does not exist or that is different from the others, go to step 4.
Step 4. If you didn't succeed in step 3 ofter $n$ repetitions, you should be conviced that the number $L=L_{n}=L_{n-1}=\ldots=L_{1}$ is a good candidate to the achieve $L=\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_{0},y_{0})} f(x,y)$. In this point you should try to use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit to proof that
$$
L=\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_{0},y_{0})} f(x,y).
$$
